# Which are all the S and A class heroes whom Garou fought?

Tags: one-punch-man

So far in the anime Garou has fought Tank Top Master, Heavy Tank Loincloth, Blue Fire, Magic Trick Man, Golden Ball and Spring Mustachio. From video segments of the manga I've seen he fought others such as

> Genos.

Which are all the S and A class heroes whom Garou fought  ?

Comment: Please consider using spoiler tags. You may have seen or read things, that isn't same for everyone else.

Comment: @ero sennin When it comes down to questions about stories, anything it's a spoiler for someone. I think that if someone don't want to be spoiled , he/she shouldnt look into any question, otherwise we should be tagging all questions. If you have any practical rule, such as all questions including content from the manga should be tagged with spoilers (with imo it would be a pain, because half questions should be tagged, but more or less reasonable) open a question for debate in meta. BTW the content posted isnt new, it's over 2 years old

Comment: Just an opinion but I think it would be best if spoiler tags are used on recent questions on currently airing anime series, especially if manga chapters that are not yet aired/adapted are discussed. While some content in the manga may have been released years before, it might be unknown to anime viewers. 'I think that if someone don't want to be spoiled , he/she shouldnt look into any question...' Even so, some may stumble upon these questions accidentally/unintentionally, no matter how unlikely it might seem and that could ruin other's viewing experiences.

Comment: @Pablo you're asking a question in relation to series which has just started its second season. Even if the content is over two years old, I'm pretty sure you asked this question because you follow the anime. There will be people who strictly follow the anime. I feel that mentioning characters of importance like you did, would take away the element of surprise for an anime only viewer. But I guess this is just my opinion. You're free to do what you think is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will include spoilers of necessity.  I'll mention the webcomic appearances for S-class (I think the manga covers all of the A-class he fought in the webcomic already, but I won't quite guarantee it).  Though keep in mind there are differences between the webcomic and manga.

### S-class

- Metal bat
- Genos
- Bang
- Watchdog Man
- Tanktop Master
- King (sort of)

In the webcomic he also fights:

> Everyone else except Blast, Metal Knight, and Drive Knight.  In several cases he fights three or more of them at the same time.

### A-class

- Blue Fire
- Heavy Tank Loincloth
- Magic Trick Man
- Golden Ball
- Spring Mustachio
- Death Gatling
- Smile Man
- Stinger
- Chain'n'toad

There's also a smattering of B-class heroes and even Mumen Rider, and a host of monsters that were classed as Demon or Dragon level threats.  A list of manga battles Garou has fought [can be found here](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Garou/Battles).

Answer (score 0):

S Class That Garou fought - METAL BAT , GENOS , BANG

look here https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Garou/Battles

Comment: There are more..